# Pinch event triggers pan event in Hammer.js

Tags: javascript, events, hammer.js, pan, pinch

I'm writing a small mobile gesture rocognizer using Hammer.js library. 
Unfortunately it seems that when the user pinchs in or pinchs out, Hammer,js triggers also some pan events.

I think it happens because , during the pinch gesture, the user's fingers make a little pan movement.

There's a way to make Hammer.js ignore the little pan movement during a pinch?

Honestly, Hammer.js documentation is not clear about this.

Here's my code:

```
                    hammer = new Hammer.Manager(myelement);
                var singleTap = new Hammer.Tap({
                    event: 'tap',
                });

                var doubleTap = new Hammer.Tap({
                    event: 'doubletap',
                    taps: 2
                });

                // SWIPE RECOGNIZERS

                var swipeLeft = new Hammer.Swipe({
                    event: 'swipeleft',
                    direction: 2
                });

                var swipeRight = new Hammer.Swipe({
                    event: 'swiperight',
                    direction: 4
                });

                var swipeUp = new Hammer.Swipe({
                    event: 'swipeup',
                    direction: 8
                });

                var swipeDown = new Hammer.Swipe({
                    event: 'swipedown',
                    direction: 16
                });


                // PINCH RECOGNIZERS
                var pinch = new Hammer.Pinch({
                    event: 'pinch',
                    pointers: 2
                });

                var pinchIn = new Hammer.Pinch({
                    event: 'pinchin',
                    pointers: 2,
                });

                var pinchOut = new Hammer.Pinch({
                    event: 'pinchout',
                    pointers: 2,
                });

                // PRESS RECOGNIZER
                var press = new Hammer.Press({
                    event: 'press',
                    pointers: 1,
                    threshold: 5,
                    time: 500
                });

                // PAN RECOGNIZER
                var pan = new Hammer.Pan({
                    event: 'pan',
                    pointers: 0
                });

                // ROTATE EVENTS RECOGNIZERS

                var rotateStart = new Hammer.Rotate({
                    event: 'rotatestart',
                    pointers: 2,
                    threshold: 0
                });

                var rotateEnd = new Hammer.Rotate({
                    event: 'rotateennd',
                    pointers: 2,
                    threshold: 0
                });

                var rotateCancel = new Hammer.Rotate({
                    event: 'rotatecancel',
                    pointers: 2,
                    threshold: 0
                });

                // ADDING RECOGNIZERS TO HAMMER 
                hammer.add([doubleTap, singleTap]);

                hammer.add([swipeDown, swipeUp, swipeRight, swipeLeft]);

                hammer.add([pan]);

                hammer.add([pinch]);
                hammer.add([press]);

                hammer.add([rotateStart, rotateEnd, rotateCancel]);

                pinchIn.recognizeWith([pan]);
                pinchOut.recognizeWith([pan]);
                pan.requireFailure([pinchIn, pinchOut]);

                // BEHAVIOUR ON TAP
                doubleTap.recognizeWith(singleTap);

                // DOUBLE/TRIPLE TAP RECOGNIZERS EXCLUSION
                singleTap.requireFailure([doubleTap]);

                //Binding Hammer's events with hammerHandler
                hammer.on("tap doubletap press rotatestart rotateend rotatecancel swipeleft swiperight swipeup swipedown pan pinch", function (event) {
                    hammerHandler(event);
                });
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: This question was very useful to implement the pinch and pan gesture! But the pan recognizer should have `pointers` 1 to work correctly also on iPad!

Answer (score 0):

I was just dealing with the same issue, and it turns out that pinch is disabled by default. You have to enable it like so:

```
hammer.get('pinch').set({enable:true});
```

Try adding that after your first line, and hopefully you should see the pinch event being reported.

Source: http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/

Comment: OP's question is not about enabling pinch. Rather, he is suggesting pinch is already working, and that after the pinch and undesired pan event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

if you use for pan just one finger, so check for 2 fingers...

```
hammertime.on('panend', function(e) {
    if(e.maxPointers > 1) { return; }
})
```